# using hyperlink in a vlookup function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

very new to this and only just managed the vlookup, anyway, 
i have a workbook which contains two Sheets. On Sheet1 I have the following formula `(=VLOOKUP(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$Y$176,3,FALSE))` which displays the ID number from Sheet2. This works correctly but how do I get to appear as a hyperlink so once clicked it goes to the specific cell it got from the vloopkup on Sheet2?

I have tried `=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$Y$176,3,FALSE`) but I get the error "Cannot get the specified file".

I would be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... this looks crazy. This should work for you. I tested it on my machine and it works:

```
=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename")), SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1) & ADDRESS(MATCH(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$176),3,,,"sheet2"),VLOOKUP(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$Y$176,3,FALSE))
```

Let's break it up a little just to explain some of the parts:

```
MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename")), SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1)
```

Returns a string [currentFileName], which is the required format for a hyperlink within a workbook.

```
MATCH(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$176),3,,,"sheet2")
```

Returns the row number of value of CZ54 in the first column of your VLookup range.

```
ADDRESS(MATCH(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$176),3,,,"sheet2")
```

Returns the address of the row found, and the column(3, from your vlookup) in sheet2.

So combined:

```
MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename")), SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1) & ADDRESS(MATCH(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$176),3,,,"sheet2")
```

Returns the actual address for the hyperlink, which is the first parameter of the `HYPERLINK` formula.

The second parameter is the Vlookup you provided, and voilà.

Edit: A warning if anyone tries to use this for a similar issue, if the lookup_array used in Match or Vlookup does not start with Row 1 or column 1 respectively, you will need to offset the values sent to ADDRESS with a +(starting row or column - 1). Example: `Match(CZ54,$A$2:$A$176)+1` instead of `MATCH(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$176)`.

Comment: Wow thank you, ive gone through this and implemented it, the strange thing is that it points to the wrong row in Sheet2, it probably to do with CZ54 being information from a lookup derived from Sheet3 CZ54 has formula =VLOOKUP(T54,Sheet3!$B$1:$O$5046,10,FALSE), this would complicate things maybe... very interesting this...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more compact version of Daniel's formula.

Using `Hyperlink` to link to another sheet in the same workbook, you can replace the reference to the workbook name with `#`.

Eg `=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!$C$10","Click Here")`

So, applying this you get

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(MATCH(E21,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$176),3,,,"sheet2"),VLOOKUP(E21,Sheet2!$A$1:$Y$176,3,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

HYPERLINK is looking for text so if you were to do something like

```
=HYPERLINK(left(VLOOKUP(CZ54,Sheet2!$A$1:$Y$176,3,FALSE),255))
```

it should return a usable hyperlink